# Adding sounds (mp3) to FlashDevelop, when I get this message?

Tags: mp3, flashdevelop

I get this error message:
col: 4: Error: An Embed variable must not have an existing value.
The error refers to the line with "[Embed(source = "../bin/03Outside.mp3")]" .
Under the first "[}, there is a red line (which I believe indicates it is what is wrong).

Here is my code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Sound

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Kendall Murray
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            [Embed(source = "../bin/03Outside.mp3")]
            var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
            mySound.load(new URLRequest("03Outside.mp3"));  
            mySound.play();
        }

    }

}
```

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to embed the sound in a different spot.

```
...
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    [Embed(source = "../bin/03Outside.mp3")]private var SndOutside:Class;

    public function Main():void 
    {
...
```

Also, if you're using URLRequest, I don't believe you need to embed the sound... you can do either or. Remove the Embeded sound and use URLRequest, or instead of using URLRequest do something like:

```
var mySound:Sound = new SndOutside();
mySound.play();
```

Where you have SndOutside embedded like I showed above.
Take a look at: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html for more info.